# You have already activated launchy 0.3.7, but your Gemfile requires launchy 0.4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

On a rails project that I know to have been working as recently as Friday I am suddenly getting this message when I try to perform any rake tasks:

```
You have already activated launchy 0.3.7, but your Gemfile requires launchy 0.4.0. Consider using bundle exec.
```

Thinking that was odd I checked out my Gemfile, I am not calling for launchy anywhere (though it is appearing in my Gemfile.lock).

When running bundle show launchy it is informing me that I am using:

```
Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/launchy-0.4.0
```

I've tried running bundle update rake, re-running bundle install, and using both rake db:create and bundle exec rake db:create. What changed?

Comment: brutal solution -> delite gemfile.lock and bundle install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're not using [RVM](https://rvm.io). I would highly recommend installing it.

Assuming that you have an RVM and, for instance, Ruby 1.9.2-p180 installed, I'd do the following:

1. create a my_project gemset:

   `rvm gemset create my_project`
2. inside the project's folder create an `.rvmrc` file, with the following line in it:

   `rvm use 1.9.2-p180@my_project`
3. run `cd .` inside the project dir and accept all the prompts;
4. install `bundler` gem:

   `gem install bundler`
5. run `bundle` command inside the project root.

That should do the trick. In my example I insist using RVM, as it will isolate all your project gems from the system ones. Once you run `bundle` command, Bundler will manage the dependencies for you, so there's obviously no need to explicitly specify `launchy` gem in your Gemfile.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that launchy is used by capybara or cucumber. Aside from doing a `gem uninstall launchy` and re-installing your bundle, I would recommend explicitly adding it to your Gemfile to avoid this issue, since something odd seems to be going on here. For example:

```
group :test do
  gem 'launcy', '=0.4.0'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your gemfile, specify the exact version of launchy that you need and run `bundle`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `open_gem` installed on your system? It gets autoloaded by `rubygems` and requires launchy, leading to nasty interactions with bundler. Try removing it.

```
sudo gem uninstall open_gem
```

See [this blog post](http://opinionated-programmer.com/2011/03/bundler-problem-you-have-already-activated-launchy-0-3-7/) for details.